# How to know all form data is validating in react-hook-form library

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form for validation in reactjs. i am using multistep form, so once one step data is validated it should go to next step. But i didn't find how to know all data is validated or not. I am using if else condition for two buttons, once all data validated, then the button will go to next step.
here's my code..

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';  
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const UserDetails = ({ setForm, formData, navigation }) => {

const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();
const onSubmit = values => {

  };
return(
<>
   <input
   type="text"
   name="fullName"
   id="fullname"
     className="form__field form-control br0 font-white"
     placeholder='Name'
     onChange={setForm}
     defaultValue={fullName}
    ref={register({ required: true })}
    />
{errors.fullName && 'First name is required'}


//here my code for validating.
   {allValid() ? (
    <button className="btn green_btn w250 font22"  onClick={next}>
                                                Next
                                            </button>
                            ) : (
  <button className="btn green_btn w250 font22" type="submit">Next</button>
  )}  
</>
)

}
```

Comment: Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeAkxVwsyMU maybe it will be helpful.